# How to view a file including git-staged changes

Tags: git, git-stage

git diff --staged allows you to view changes between HEAD and the staged changes.

How do I view the full file as it would exist in HEAD if I were to commit the staged changes?
How do I view a specific subset of lines from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view the staged version of a file using:

```
git cat-file -p :./FILENAME
```

The leading `:` causes git to read from the index. The `./` gets it to look in 
the current directory, this part may be omitted if you specify a path relative 
to the top of the repository rather than to your current directory.

You can view a specific subset of lines by piping the output from that to 
another command to do the desired limiting as for any other file.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I do "git cat-file -p :./FILENAME.php > temporary.php". This way I can view the file with vi, with syntax highlighting and all. Cool. Thanks :)

Comment: You could also pipe to `vim +':set ft=php' -` to do that without a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git ls-files --cached --stage
100644 f009acdec84ee338ec99c92920d603a67241608f 0       README

Guest@HOME-PC ~/doubt (master)
$ git cat-file -p f009acdec84ee338ec99c92920d603a67241608f

One
Teo
```

Comment: This **would** show the file with staged changes. The `--cached` option isn't actually needed, it's the default.